# Change From email address in MVCMailer 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcmailer

Does anyone know how to change the from email address in code to override the web.config settings.

What I'm trying to do is allow someone to complete an online form and when the recipicant receives the email, it will be from the senders email address.

But at the momment it is just displaying the default in web.config.

-----------------Web.config-------------------------

```
<smtp from="some-email@gmail.com" deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
                <network host="localhost" />
                <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\temp\"/>
            </smtp>
```

---

```
public virtual MvcMailMessage DirectotyEmail(string emailTo, string fromName, string arrivalDate, string departureDate, string message)
            {
            ViewBag.FromName        = fromName;
            ViewBag.ArrivalDate     = arrivalDate;
            ViewBag.DepartureDate   = departureDate;
            ViewBag.Message         = message;
            return Populate(x =>
            {
                x.Subject = "Accommodation Enquery form";
                x.ViewName = "DirectoryEmail";
                x.To.Add(emailTo.ToString());
                //x.From.Address("test@email.com");
                x.IsBodyHtml = true;
            });
            }
```

---

```
X-Sender: some-email@gmail.com << Need this to be the email that user entered when submitting form
X-Receiver: test@mail.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: some-email@gmail.com << Need this to be the email that user entered when submitting form
To: test@mail.com
Date: 26 Mar 2013 11:08:57 +0000
Subject: Accommodation Enquery form
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

Comment: You can try with `x.From = new MailAddress("test@email.com"); x.Sender = new MailAddress("test@email.com");`

Comment: Sorry my mistake, should remember to compile before testing :-( thanks its work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the web config provided sender with the `Sender` property and the from address with the `From` property. Both properties expecting an `MailAddress` object, so you need to write:

```
return Populate(x =>
{
    x.Subject = "Accommodation Enquery form";
    x.ViewName = "DirectoryEmail";
    x.To.Add(emailTo.ToString());
    x.From = new MailAddress("test@email.com");
    x.Sender = new MailAddress("test@email.com");
    x.IsBodyHtml = true;
});
```

Comment: Hi nemesv i forgot to compile before testing, marked as answer, thanks for that, I think it would be helpfull if it was in the documentation

Comment: It is in the documentation at least on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx